# Java Digits Validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, model-view-controller

I'm using validation in a int attribute:

```
@Digits(integer=6,fraction=0)
private Integer idOrder;
```

But I wanted this attribute has exactly 6 digits.

How can I do that? (Using JSP+Spring+Hibernate)

Comment: What isn't working about this?

Comment: I want this attribute with 6 digits like: 000000, 020123, 123452.

Comment: Can you give an example of an integer that should not be allowed that will be allowed with the code in your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you need the 6 digits, I think you should use a String to the property. If in some situations you need it as int, you make a

```
 public int getIdOrder(){ return Integer.parseInt(idOrder);}
```

On the String you can use pattern validation. It would be somethind like this:

```
@Pattern(regexp="\\d{6}")
private String idOrder;
```

Another option, is keep the idOrder a int and make a getter for the string:

```
public String getIdOrgetAsString(){
    String s = "000000" + idOrder;
    return s.substring(s.length() - 6);
}
```

Anyway, there are some options.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your validation works at all?

The Hibernate documentation says:

> Check whether the property is a number having up to integer digits and fraction fractional digits. [1](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/)

What means exactly 6 digits? Are leading zeros supported? Or should the number be between 100.000 and 999.999. In the first case, I guess your number should be a String (with @Length), and in the second case, I guess you should use @Min and @Max.

Comment: It is not working.

Exactly 6 digits I mean 6 numbers, like: 000000, 020123, 123452,...

Comment: In that case, using a String with @Length should work. If it does not, I guess your validation does not work at all. Or does a String not fit in your use case? And so, why not?

Comment: I must use int ou Integer. @Lenght just works with Strings.

Comment: @RenatoShumi An `int` never has leading digits, so your code is already correct as far as I can tell.